# Building a body signed oauth xml request for LTI Outcomes service using pecl oauth

Tags: php, oauth, lti

I'm using the pecl oAuth library, is it possible to build a body signed oauth request that looks like:

```
POST http://www.imsglobal.org/developers/BLTI/service_handle.php HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:80
Content-Length: 757
Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_nonce="29f90c047a44b2ece73d00a09364d49b",
oauth_timestamp="1313350943",oauth_consumer_key="lmsng.school.edu",
oauth_body_hash="v%2BxFnmDSHV%2Fj29qhxLwkFILrtPo%3D",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_signature="8auRpRdPY2KRXUrOyz3HKCs92y8%3D"
Content-type: application/xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
... more xml data ...
```

I'm trying to communicate with Instructure's Canvas LMS using the IMS Global LTI standard interface.  The [Outcomes Service](http://www.imsglobal.org/lti/v1p1pd/ltiIMGv1p1pd.html#_Toc309649691) lets you send scores back to the LMS using [oauth signed xml messages](http://www.imsglobal.org/lti/v1p1pd/ltiIMGv1p1pd.html#_Toc309649688)

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out pecl oAuth doesn't support oaut_body_hash currently.

I ended up using the oAuth library from this google code repository http://code.google.com/p/oauth/ and computing the body has myself:

```
$bodyHash = base64_encode(sha1($body, TRUE)); // build oauth_body_hash
$consumer = new \OAuthConsumer($key, $secret);
$request = \OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, '', 'POST', $endpoint, array('oauth_body_hash' => $bodyHash) );
$request->sign_request(new \OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, '');
$header = $request->to_header() . "\r\nContent-Type: application/xml\r\n"; // add content type header
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard [`OAuth::generateSignature`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.generatesignature.php) function permits extra parameters as a third argument. This can be used to pass a custom body hash parameter:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($credentials["oauthKey"], $credentials["oauthSecret"]);

$timestamp = time();
$oauth->setTimestamp($timestamp);

$nonce = mt_rand();
$oauth->setNonce($nonce);

$bodyHash = base64_encode(sha1($content, true)); // $content contains the body
$sig = $oauth->generateSignature('GET', $url, Array("oauth_body_hash" => $bodyHash));
```

We can then use this to build our OAuth header:

```
$header = array
(
    'Content-Type: application/xml'
);
$header[] = 'Authorization: OAuth '.
            'oauth_version="1.0",'.
            'oauth_nonce="'.$nonce.'",'.
            'oauth_timestamp="'.$timestamp.'",'.
            'oauth_body_hash="'.$bodyHash.'",'.
            'oauth_consumer_key="'.$credentials["oauthKey"].'",'.
            'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",'.
            'oauth_signature="'.urlencode($sig).'"';
```